# AWS CloudFormation: unable to create Route53 record resource for URL to URL mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I am deploying my application to AWS using CloudFormation. I am creating a Route53 record mapping URL to URL. But it is failing when I deployed my template.

This is my resources in the template.

```
WebDNS:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: waiyanhein.com.
      Comment: Weighted PRs for frontends.
      RecordSets:
        - Name: waiyanhein.com.
          Type: CNAME
          TTL: '900'
          SetIdentifier: Frontend
          Weight: 5
          ResourceRecords:
            - http://patheindirectorytesting.eba-zxqi6pge.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/
```

When I deployed, I got the following error.

```
{
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/patheindirectory/dd7eb5b0-e96c-11ea-bcdf-02e29081c656",
            "EventId": "36f3bc50-e975-11ea-b9b2-0ae6d6014b56",
            "StackName": "patheindirectory",
            "LogicalResourceId": "patheindirectory",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/patheindirectory/dd7eb5b0-e96c-11ea-bcdf-02e29081c656",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
            "Timestamp": "2020-08-28T21:27:03.035000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "The following resource(s) failed to create: [WebDNS]. "
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/patheindirectory/dd7eb5b0-e96c-11ea-bcdf-02e29081c656",
            "EventId": "WebDNS-CREATE_FAILED-2020-08-28T21:27:02.244Z",
            "StackName": "patheindirectory",
            "LogicalResourceId": "WebDNS",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup",
            "Timestamp": "2020-08-28T21:27:02.244000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_FAILED",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "[RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name waiyanhein.com. is not permitted at apex in zone waiyanhein.com.]",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Comment\":\"Weighted PRs for frontends.\",\"HostedZoneName\":\"waiyanhein.com.\",\"RecordSets\":[{\"Type\":\"CNAME\",\"ResourceRecords\":[\"http://patheindirectorytesting.eba-zxqi6pge.eu-west-1.
elasticbeanstalk.com/\"],\"SetIdentifier\":\"Frontend\",\"TTL\":\"900\",\"Weight\":\"5\",\"Name\":\"waiyanhein.com.\"}]}"
        },
```

What is wrong with my template and how can I fix it?

I tried using this.

```
WebDNS:
        Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
        Properties:
          HostedZoneName: waiyanhein.com.
          Comment: Weighted PRs for frontends.
          RecordSets:
            - Name: waiyanhein.com.
              Type: A
              AliasTarget:
                  DNSName: patheindirectorytesting.eba-zxqi6pge.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
                  EvaluateTargetHealth: true
                  HostedZoneId: Z1LQECGX5PH1X
              SetIdentifier: Frontend
              Weight: 5
```

I got this error this time.

```
{
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/patheindirectory/bb2b3cd0-e9ef-11ea-9251-06755b8a246a",
            "EventId": "84c9cfb0-e9f1-11ea-9a83-0655dfaca74c",
            "StackName": "patheindirectory",
            "LogicalResourceId": "patheindirectory",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/patheindirectory/bb2b3cd0-e9ef-11ea-9251-06755b8a246a",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
            "Timestamp": "2020-08-29T12:16:51.229000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "The following resource(s) failed to create: [WebDNS]. . Rollback requested by user."
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/patheindirectory/bb2b3cd0-e9ef-11ea-9251-06755b8a246a",
            "EventId": "WebDNS-CREATE_FAILED-2020-08-29T12:16:50.249Z",
            "StackName": "patheindirectory",
            "LogicalResourceId": "WebDNS",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup",
            "Timestamp": "2020-08-29T12:16:50.249000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_FAILED",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "[Tried to create an alias that targets patheindirectorytesting.eba-zxqi6pge.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com., type A in zone Z1LQECGX5PH1X, but the alias target name does not lie within the target
 zone, RRSet with DNS name waiyanhein.com., type A, SetIdentifier Frontend cannot be created as a non-weighted set exists with the same name and type.]",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Comment\":\"Weighted PRs for frontends.\",\"HostedZoneName\":\"waiyanhein.com.\",\"RecordSets\":[{\"AliasTarget\":{\"HostedZoneId\":\"Z1LQECGX5PH1X\",\"DNSName\":\"patheindirectorytesting.eba-zx
qi6pge.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com\",\"EvaluateTargetHealth\":\"true\"},\"Type\":\"A\",\"SetIdentifier\":\"Frontend\",\"Weight\":\"5\",\"Name\":\"waiyanhein.com.\"}]}"
        },
```

Comment: A dns record is not the same thing as a URL. You are trying to set the value of the CNAME to a URL instead of a dns name.

Comment: What do I need to use to get what I want to achieve?

Comment: You need to create an alias record (not a CNAME) pointing to `patheindirectorytesting.eba-zxqi6pge.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`. You can not CNAME a top level domain.

Answer (score 0):

Since your EB domain has region name (`eu-west-1`) in it, I think the best way would be to setup an alias record for it:

- [Creating an Amazon Route 53 record that routes traffic to your Elastic Beanstalk environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html#routing-to-beanstalk-environment-create-resource-record-set)

To do this, you need to get HostedZoneId for your region, which would be `Z1LQECGX5PH1X` as listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/elasticbeanstalk.html#elasticbeanstalk_region).

Subsequently, your RecordSet could be:

```
    WebDNS:
        Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
        Properties:
          HostedZoneName: waiyanhein.com.
          Comment: Weighted PRs for frontends.
          RecordSets:
            - Name: waiyanhein.com.
              Type: A
              AliasTarget:
                  DNSName: patheindirectorytesting.eba-zxqi6pge.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
                  EvaluateTargetHealth: true
                  HostedZoneId: Z1LQECGX5PH1X
              SetIdentifier: Frontend
              Weight: 5
```

Comment: Hi, @Macin. I tried using this. I am still getting the error. I have updated the question to include the error. Pease, have a  look.

Comment: @WaiYanHein Hi. The new error indicates that you already have existing waiyanhein.com. record which is not weight. So obviously you cannot have duplication. Thus you have to check why you have second record? Was it Created manually in console or in other not shown part of your template?

Comment: @WaiYanHein Have you managed to figure out why there was a duplicate records?

Comment: I tried deleting existing A record with that domain name. I deployed again. It is still throwing error.

Comment: @WaiYanHein Are you sure you must create `Name: waiyanhein.com.`? Maybe it must be different domain, e.g., `Name: app.waiyanhein.com.` or `Name: api.waiyanhein.com.`?

Comment: Hi Marcin. It is waiyanhein.com. Literally this is what I am trying to do. When I visit, waiyanhein.com, it will show my website deployed on Beanstalk. Of course using Route53.

Comment: Do you think maybe it is because my ElasticBeanstalk is using SingleInstance environment type?

Comment: @WaiYanHein Hi. The error is about duplicate records. It shouldn't matter if its single-instance or load-balanced. But earlier you wrote that domain waiyanhein.com is working. Why do you want to create a  second one?

Comment: No, the domain was working because there is another record created in the console just to test. Now, it has been deleted. I am trying to create it now in using the CloudFormation instead.

Comment: @WaiYanHein How did it go without the per-existing record?